# Can Mule Enricher message use instead of session to retain properties across transport barrier? What's the pros cons?

Tags: java, mule, mule-component, mule-esb

We can inbound request properties set into Mule session and get it across transport barrier. Enricher message can also facilitate that using payload and flow var.

Answer (score 0):

If the target system needs more information than the source system can provide then enricher is preferable. e.g - If you need to call some other external system to get additional information then you can easily get that into a flowvar without impacting existing payload.

Answer (score 0):

Session Variable and Mule Enricher are basically the same. When using a session variable it is tied to a message for its entire lifecycle, across multiple flows, applications, and even servers.

**CONS:**

- If you put any large objects in the Session, you are asking for serious trouble! As the number of visitors increase, your server will experience dramatic performance woes by placing large objects in the Session!
- Since Session variables can be created on the fly, used whenever, and do not require the developer to dispose of them explicitly, the overuse of Session variables can lead to very unreadable and unmaintainable code.